# Where should i store the endpoint of the service registry server?

Tags: go, microservices, consul, service-discovery

I'm learning about microservices recently. I tried using consul for service discovery. 
I wonder if I deploy the consul server, so where should i store endpoint of that server? Is it good to hard code in env variable of each services?

Comment: In consul's kv store :)

Comment: Normally you pass such configuration data either via a env var or a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### All of the 3 following options are supported in the following precedence order:

1. Command line arguments
2. Environment Variables
3. Configuration files

#### For the Linux Configuration File Option

Create

> **/etc/consul.d/config.json**

The key is **start_join** with value of the IP of Consul server e.g.,

```
"start_join": [ "10.128.0.2" ]
```

For a cluster solution of more than one Consul instances:

```
"start_join": [ "10.128.0.2", "10.128.0.3" ]
```

The default *server* port is **8300** but you may override with the **ports** object offering multiple ports to override e.g.,

```
"ports": {
   "server": 8300
}
```

For a full reference of the available options, you may check the [Consul Documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html), [and all the available ports options](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#ports)